# CSS transition is jumpy on opacity fade out

Tags: animation, css-animations, transition, visibility, opacity

I'm working on a breadcrumb menu that has a link appear all the way to the right once the menu becomes sticky to let users scroll back up to the top of the page. The breadcrumb `<nav>` has `position:sticky` and an event listener is used to detect when it has "stuck." I then use CSS to target the `breadcrumb-arrow` `<div>` and then transition it so its opacity fades in and out again if the user scrolls back up or clicks it.

The code was working, but the CSS animation to make it fade out was jumpy. Specifically, the border just disappeared with no transition, and the `<a>` tag started to fade out and then just vanished before the transition ended.

HTML:

```html
<nav class="breadcrumbs noselect">
    <div class="bread-bag">
        <ul class="l-breadcrumb">
            <li><a>Link 1</a> &gt; </li>
            <li><a>Link 2</a> &gt; </li>
            <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- This is what fades in and out -->
        <div class="breadcrumb-arrow">
            <a class="toTop">&uuarr;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
.breadcrumbs {
    position: relative;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #252524;
    background: #101112;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 20;
    top: -1px;
    padding-top: calc(0em + 1px);
}
.breadcrumb-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 48px;
    text-align: right;
    background: #101112;
    border-left: 1px solid #101112;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1s linear, visibility 0s;
    z-index: 30;
}
.is-pinned .breadcrumb-arrow {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    border-left: 1px solid #232425
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had seen code posted elsewhere on Stackoverflow and other websites, where people suggested setting visibility to `0s` transition while also using `transition: all 1s linear` (or some other time duration) for everything else. This is what broke it.

Simply remove `visibility 0s` and the CSS animation will work fine.

I'm not sure if older browsers needed this, or maybe it's a Firefox-only glitch, but once I removed that CSS, all elements faded in and out without error. I've only tested in Firefox on macOS, but hopefully this helps someone in the future.

```css
.breadcrumb-arrow {transition: all 1s linear}
```